# DDALine in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wrote DDALine algorithm in Visual-Studio with C++, but Visual-Studio said

> 'putpixel': identifier not found.....

I'm using `graphics.h`, but is doesn't work ??

my source code

```
#include "graphics.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "dos.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"

void ddaline(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int color)
{

int dx,dy,len,i;
float xinc,yinc,x,y;
dx=x2-x1;
dy=y2-y1;
if (abs(dx)>abs(dy))
len=abs(dx);
else
len=abs(dy);
     if (len!=0)
{
xinc=((dx*1.0)/(len));
yinc=((dy*1.0)/(len));
 }
 x=x1;
 y=y1;
  for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
  {
  putpixel(x,y,color);
  x=x+xinc;
  y=y+yinc;
  }

       }
     void main()
  {

 ddaline(1,1,640,400,4);



  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<graphics.h>` and `<conio.h>` are not C++ standard headers. Do you have them beside your project?!

You should test your code in Turbo C++ and maybe with DOSBOX (new Windows versions don't support DOS full screen mode)